# Get an interval of values possible in regression using sci-kit learn machine learning

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to use regression to predict a value. For a given set of independent variables, I get a fixed number as the expected value. However, is it possible to get a range of value, so as to say that the maximum possible value be say x and minimum possible value be say y.

Using

```
regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()

regr.fit(X_train, Y_train)  

pred = regr.predict([[a, b]])
```

The value of pred comes out be say 10 , but i would rather want something like max = 12 and min = 8

Simply saying a range of values.

**UPDATE**

Tried looking into GMM, not sure if that work for this.

Tried Gausian processes but it again give a single value something like 11.137631, which really doesn't as i am looking for a range of value rather than a single value.

Comment: Sounds like Bayes, MCMC and high likelihood interval calculation to me.

Comment: Just go for Gaussian Processes, they are implemented in scikit learn and do what you need out of the box

Comment: Do you want possible limits for your output forecast? It's not clear for me what you exactly want.

Comment: Do you want an interval instead of a scalar value in which output value is?

Comment: Yes, limits as to the max possible value and minimum possible value rather than a single precise value, yes an interval

Comment: Do you want a confidence interval for your output value? Which is the probability parameter for the interval? In theory your output value could be **any**, but with different probability.

Comment: Please look for pred_ints() function in the following web page: http://blog.datadive.net/prediction-intervals-for-random-forests/. It's for random forests, but may be it's easy to tune.

Comment: yes confidence interval, where it forecasted value lies in between that range with high probablity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The linear regression always gives same result for a given input vector, however using a random forest regressor in iteration gives different result on each iteration and that can be used to get a Minimum and maximum possible value from a given input vector forecast.